# Existe alguma maneira de diminuir ou agilizar esta VIEW ? MSSQL, software próprio usando ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

```
AS 
WITH 
Grupos AS(SELECT contato.IDContato, contato_Grupos.IDGrupo, contato_Grupos.IDContato AS IDContexto FROM contato, contato_Grupos WHERE (contato_Grupos.IDGrupo = contato.IDContato)),
Membros AS (SELECT contato.IDContato, contato_Grupos.IDContato AS ID FROM contato, contato_Grupos, Grupos WHERE contato_Grupos.IDGrupo = Grupos.IDGrupo AND contato.IDContato = Grupos.IDContexto),
Instituicoes AS(SELECT contato.IDContato, Grupos.IDContexto FROM contato, Grupos WHERE Grupos.IDContato = contato.IDContato AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM AspNetUsers WHERE AspNetUsers.Id = Grupos.IDContato))

SELECT contato.*, contato.IDMembro AS IDContexto FROM contato UNION
SELECT contato.*, Grupos.IDContexto AS IDContexto FROM contato, Grupos WHERE (Grupos.IDContato = contato.IDContato) UNION
SELECT contato.*, Membros.ID AS IDContexto FROM contato, Membros WHERE Membros.IDContato = contato.IDContato UNION
SELECT contato.*, Instituicoes.IDContexto AS IDContexto FROM contato, Instituicoes WHERE Instituicoes.IDContato = contato.IDMembro
```

Comment: Difícil qual alguém tenha uma resposta concreta para isso, teria que saber a estrutura das suas tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

Carregue a query no Microsoft SQL Server Managment e clique no icone

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O programa analiza para você, diz onde estão seus gargalos e sugere a criação
de índices caso sejam necessários.